# Parallax Effect CSS?

Tags: html, css, parallax

I am trying to create a simple parallax effect using css, I have the following [code](http://jsfiddle.net/KarinaMcG/6pgb8/4/) which created the effect I am looking for, however it seems to zoom the image in, so half of my image is cut off at the corners.  How can I amend what I have so that it keeps the actual size of my image?

```
<div id="slide4" class="slide" data-stellar-background-ratio="0" data-slide="4"> </div>
    <div id="slide2" class="slide" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5" data-slide="2"> </div>

#slide4 {background-image: url("http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-m95Wunj4M-g/T8zFSAFdh4I/AAAAAAAAEhg/y9W8e-Iu4WQ/s1600/Flower-wallpaper-32.jpg");
background-size: contain;
float: left;
margin-top:20px;
height: 450px;}

.slide {background-attachment: fixed;
height: 100%;
position: inherit;
width: 100%;}
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
background-size: cover;
```

as you can see in [this fork](http://jsfiddle.net/reimersjan/K6V75/1/) of your fiddle

Comment: You will also need to use CSS prefixes if using this method i.e  `-webkit-`, `-moz` and `-o-`.

Comment: @JamieRead — Why? Support for unprefixed background-size has been around for ages.

Comment: @Quentin Exactly. [http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts](http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts)

Comment: I was using `background-size:cover;` at first but this seem to zoom my image in even more?